# The zero set of continuous real functon

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a continuous real function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ be the set of all $p\in X$ at which $f(p)=0$. Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.

**First solution:** Let $W=Z(f)^c$ and we'll prove that $W$ is open. Taking some $p\in W$ then $f(p)\neq 0$. WLOG we can suppose that $f(p)>0$. We must prove that $\exists r>0$ s.t. $N_r(p)\subset W$.

Taking $\varepsilon=\frac{f(p)}{2}>0$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall t\in X$ and $d_X(t,p)<\delta$ implies that $|f(t)-f(p)|<\frac{f(p)}{2}$ or $\frac{f(p)}{2}<f(t)<\frac{3f(p)}{2}$. Then $r:=\delta$ and we get $N_{r}(p)\subset Z(f)^c$. Hence $Z(f)$ is closed subset of $X$.

**Second solution:** Let $p$ is a limit point of $Z(f)$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $N'_{\varepsilon}(p)\cap Z(f)\neq \varnothing$. Taking $\varepsilon \in \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ we get sequence $\{t_n\}$ s.t $t_n\neq p, t_n\in Z(f)$ and $t_n\to p$. Using that Caunchy and Heine definitions are equivalent we get that: $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f(t_n)=f(p)$ but all $f(t_n)=0$. Then $f(p)=0$ and $p\in Z(f)$. Hence $Z(f)$ is closed set.

Are both proofs true?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but it is much easier just to say $\{0\}$ is closed, so $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed (as a third solution, maybe).

Comment: @Clayton, Great solution! $\{0\}$ is closed because every finite set is closed. $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed since $f$ is continuous. Right?

Comment: Are these proofs true?

Comment: All finite sets in a $T_1$ space are closed. Spaces like $R^n$ (and meteric spaces) are Hausdorff and therefore $T_1$. thus yes your proof is true.

Comment: @RaziehNoori, Sorry. What is $T_1$ space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space